# PHP POST returns Array instead of the value of select options?

Tags: php

I'm trying to allow users to select multiple items and post the selected items to the next page using PHP.

The process above works fine but the problem that I have right now is each item has a dropdown menu with some colours in it. the colours are the same.

what I need to do is to allow the users to select 1 colour for each selected item and send it to the next page.

This should be simple but for some reason all i get in the next page is "Array" instead of the value of selected option!

This is my code:

First page:

```
    $products_list .= '<div align="center" style="width:150px; height:100px; float:left; border:solid 1px #666; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <input style="float:left;" type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="'.$id.'" />
    <img width="67" src="../inventory_images/'.$id.'.jpg"  /><br />
    '.$product_name.'<br />
    <select name="colours[]">
    <option >Choose a Colour</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    </div>';


echo $products_list;
```

and on the second page i have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){

// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
$products_list = "";
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){

$colours = $_POST['colours'];


//MYSQL QUERIES ETC GOES HERE....

$products_list .= ''.$product_name.' and '.$colours.'';
}

echo $products_list ;
```

on the second page the `$product_name` for all the selected items gets echo-ed properly and correctly but the `$colours` show Array.

could someone please advise on this ?

Thanks

EDIT:

Please note that `$_POST['colours'];` is returning Array on the second page.

Comment: name="colours[]" this is array use name="colours" instead

Comment: <select name="colours[]">  change to ->  <select name="colours">

Comment: I wish I could downvote those comments. And OP, the colors are what is in the array. do a print_r of $colours and you would see whatever they selected. You need to loop over the array to get the colors out. [Foreach](http://www.php.net/foreach)

Comment: @bksi, i did use `name="colours"` too but I get `Choose a Colour` for all of the selected item.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, print_r will return number 1 for all the $colours!!

Comment: will it? print_r would display whatever colors that are selected. So if the value of each selected option was 1, then yes, it would show 1 for all $colours.

Comment: Hm it should return the selected option instead. Oh wait, you don't have form tag. Use form to wrap your select tag and you will get the desired result

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, its not though... the value of each option is shown in my first code above! I don't even use numbers in any of the option values!

Comment: Also, you would want to number the keys in the arrays or else you won't be able to correlate the check boxes to the select boxes after post. So `check_list[1], colours[1]`...`check_list[2], colours[2]`...etc for however many boxes you have. Then on post `check_list[1]` would go with `colours[1]`...etc.

Comment: @bksi, i do have form tags. the echo $product_list is within form tags.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, numbering the keys will return 1 product on the next page. the whole point of doing it the way I did was to allow the users to select multiple items at one time.

Comment: give each of them a different number. Hence why I was showing [1] and [2]...etc. You can specify the key name in the form field name. The problem if you don't number them is what Abra is saying. Checkboxes that aren't checked don't show up in the post data. So if you have 4 checkboxes, all named `test[]`, check checkboxes 1 and 3 then post you will have `$_POST['test'][0]` and `$_POST['test'][1]` set. But each select box will be submitted so you have `[0]`-`[3]` in those and no way to know which checkbox goes to which select.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, the checkboxes and the dropdown menu's are created dynamically based on the MYSQL database! how can I give them different numbers dynamically?

Comment: Increment a number on each loop. Before the loop `$i=0` then name each field `test[$i]` and at the end of each loop `$i++` to add 1 to `$i`.

Comment: You could also just use the `$id` -> `name="check_list['.$id.']"`/`name="colours['.$id.']"`, and then `foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $key =>$selected){ $colours = $_POST['colours'][$key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the checkbox tied to the select you will need to hardcode the index numbers (1 in this example) since it is possible that a checkbox will not be checked and therefor not submitted.

```
<input typ="checkbox" name="check_list[1]">
<select name="colours[1]">
<option >Choose a Colour</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Then just:

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $selected) {
    echo $_POST['colours'][$key]; // use the key from the associated checkbox
}
```

If any of the selects will be a multiple select then you will need to do something like this:

```
<select name="colours[1][]" multiple>
<select name="colours[2]">
```

Then:

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $selected) {
    echo is_array($_POST['colours'][$key]) ? implode(',', $_POST['colours'][$key]) : $_POST['colours'][$key];
}
```